# Image Icon is returning null pointer exception even though the image is there in the path I specified

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, embedded-resource, imageicon

I am trying to put an image in my application but I always get nullpointerexception error. I have put the image in a package called "res" and specified the path as (getClass().getResource("/res/BargainG.png")) but it seems to not work for me. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong please?

[image: image place]

```
jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/res/BargainG.png")));
```

And here is the error I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:217)
at com.BargainG.BargainG.initComponents(BargainG.java:227)
at com.BargainG.BargainG.<init>(BargainG.java:20)
at com.BargainG.BargainG$8.run(BargainG.java:357)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource) to see if your configuration matches the example. One difference is you don't need the leading "/". Have you specified your classpath correctly?

Comment: @camickr It's ironic that the examples in the link show a `.png` in the images, while the code is loading a `.gif`! What the..? Note that the leading slash would make it work from a class in *any* package. I would never recommend trying to access a resource by a relative path, like shown there.

Comment: OP have you checked the image makes it into the Jar? AFAIU a resource must be under the `src` package to be included in the archive.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/res/BargainG.png")
```

or with

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/res/BargainG.png")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try getting the image with this piece of code:

```
ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/BargainG.png"));
```

Make sure your "res" folder is inside your build path.

Comment: Please, downvoters, consider adding a comment to an answer you downvote to promote improving the answer. Thanks.